# should I use dnf in place of yum in RHEL/CentOS 7.9?

Tags: yum, dnf

I just started using CentOS 9, but I use version 7.9 in a work environment.  I am somewhat antiquated and slow to change... I use ifconfig, kill -9, and yum....

I did a `yum install dnf` successfully in RHEL 7.9; should I start using dnf in place of how I've used yum, while still using RHEL 7.9  ?

- dnf update
- dnf install
- dnf remove
- dnf clean all
- dnf history sync

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the other way and use `yum` in CentOS 9. DNF was introduced in Fedora and RHEL 8 planned to switch to DNF but to make it less confusing [DNF was renamed to YUM 4 in RHEL 8](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/managing-software-packages_configuring-basic-system-settings) and the `yum` command is [still available in RHEL both 8 and 9](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html-single/managing_software_with_the_dnf_tool/index#con_software-management-tools-in-red-hat-enterprise-linux-9_managing-software-with-the-dnf-tool) (`yum` is only a symlink to `dnf` on RHEL/CentOS 9).

Most of the commands work the same way with both `dnf`/`yum` on RHEL 8/9 and the "old" `yum` on RHEL 7 so if your goal is to be able to use the same command in both 7 and 9 (and possibly 8) you can use `yum update`/`install`/`remove`... everywhere.

DNF (or YUM 4) available in RHEL 7 is only [technological preview](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/7.6_release_notes/technology_previews_system_and_subscription_management), so it is possible you will encounter some bugs or issues that you wouldn't encounter with YUM.

Comment: Like using `service <name> start` basically invokes `systemctl start <name>` , in rhel/centos 9 `yum` and `dnf` are still 2 separate entities correct?

Comment: No, on RHEL  `yum` is literally just symlink to `dnf`. (I had it wrong initially, because in Fedora `yum` used to be a separate script after yum was replaced by dnf, but looks like in RHEL it was always just a symlink, I checked with the latest CentOS 8 image.)